# Update UUID of an existing Couchdb cluster

Tags: couchdb

I have a Couchdb 2.x cluster which I configured some time ago. By mistake (and for lack of documentation at the time), I set a different UUID for each node in the cluster in `/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d/10-admins.ini`:

```
[couchdb]
uuid = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Can I fix the issue now and set the same UUID for each node or I'm risking some data loss/corruption? What's exactly the consequence of having a different UUID for each node? So far the cluster has been working just fine.